# Get value of property by name

Tags: c#, linq

Let's say there's a class called Student

```
public class Student 
{
     public string studentId {get; set;}
     public string Name {get; set;}
     public int age {get; set;} 
}
```

I want to get the value from the property `age` in `Student` object, how do I do that *dynamically*? As in, I have a *string* `x`, and want to get the value from property `x` in `student` object, how can I retrieve the value that belongs to property `x`?

Comment: Switch/case? Or reflection if you want to go that route but in both cases you’ll have to handle situations where such an attribute doesn’t exist. Is this possibly an XY problem? What do you need this for?

Comment: Have a look at *Reflection*: `int result = (int)typeof(Student).GetProperty("age").GetValue(myStudent, new object[0]);`

Comment: They are called `property` in c# tho.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko what does `new object[0]` do here?

Comment: @superninja: since we *don't* call *indexer* (but a simple property) we provide an *empty array of indexes* - `new object[0]`